# jQuery Validation plugin with dynamically added controls

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, jquery-templates

In ASP.Net, I'm adding controls dynamically using jQuery.tmpl.

I'm initializing the validator in the `$(document).ready() function` with `$("#form1").validate();`, my dynamic controls have `class="required"`, and I'm calling `$("#form1").valid()` on a click event.

Static controls on the page validate, but controls added dynamically do not.  What's wrong here?

Also, the dynamic controls make the validator act weird, showing and hiding the validation message as I click on different controls.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wY6xt/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the plug-in requires controls being validated to have unique names.  The controls being added here all have the same name so the plug-in is acting crazy.

Here is the example fixed to work with unique names: http://jsfiddle.net/wY6xt/3/

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding rules to the controls which you add dynamically? Check out this [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-js-how-to-add-rules-to-controls-getting-created-dynamically-as-per-the-users-wish). Given below is the way to do it. I think since controls are added on the fly it is not able to associate the rules (in your case classes) to the controls (I am not so sure but I think it is worth a try).

```
$("#txtEmail_1").rules("add", "required");
```

HTH

Comment: That would probably work, but I was hoping to avoid that. I've seen in some very old posts that there was to be a `.refresh()` method, but it's been removed

Comment: There are two gotchas in this http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29 Fields with Brackets and dots and multiple forms. HTH

Comment: I don't think this applies. The controls don't have names and it's only 1 form.

Comment: then that could be a problem :-)....since it says "The name attribute is required for input elements, the validation plugin doesn't work without it."

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that after your post.  I tried adding names, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Definitely not a cache problem (it's clear), I've even rebooted since yesterday and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
Jquery validation cannot be applied to dynamic controls added on the fly due to the unique name/id constraint.
My solution is to a special class name to your dynamic control and use the class name to validate.
In your question your dynamic control has a class name "required", so you can do the following,

```
$(.required).each(function(){ $(this).rules('add', {required:true, messages:{required: 'Required Field'}});});
```

It works for me. 
Hope it can help you also.